# jenkins build pipeline plugin add text to build box?

Tags: java, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Is it possible to add text to the build boxes in the build pipeline plugin (v1.4.2) for Jenkins.
For example, in the diagram below I would like to add release info under the timestamp in the "#1 dev" build that will propagate to the next step. Parameters don't appear to do this here.

[image: build pipeline]

Comment: Under "Configure" there are some check boxes for showing parameter level info. One of them is: 'Show pipeline parameters in revision box', select YES there and make sure your job has a custom parameter injected / available during job execution (which will hold: BUILD_01). It'll give you what you want but only in the first "Gray" Box. At least you won't end up repeating the same "BUILD_01" variable / value in all colored boxes in the pipeline. NOTE: Beware, this plugin does NOT mask any variable/values!! so your little trick is better than using this if you have any password variable/var=passwd

Answer (score 0):

Some small source mods got it done. ie. "BUILD_01" below.

[image]

Comment: Can you share what you did. I'd like to do the same shenzi!